# how do I calculate the Euler characteristic of a Klein bottle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle, mobius-band

I guess I have to use that it is a closed surface (manifold) and therefore
its boundary is empty, so then I gotta use Gauss-Bonnet easily (but I just cannot think
of how to use it.)

i.e. $$\chi(\textit{Klein Bottle})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\int_{\textit{Klein Bottle}}K\,d\sigma$$

I was thinking on using that a Klein bottle is homeomorphic to 2 "glued" Möbius
strips, but how from then...?

P.S. this is from my first course on Differential Geometry, so talkings on higher-level courses wouldn't help me at all

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the Euler characteristic using triangulation ?

Comment: yup but I only have seen it for "cute" examples like polyhedra and toruses.

Comment: Gauss-Bonnet applies only to *orientable* surfaces!

Answer (score 6):

This is one triangulation of the Klein bottle, with vertex $V$ and edges $a, b, c$:

[image]

Can you calculate the Euler characteristic from this?

Comment: This is not, strictly speaking, a triangulation. Using Hatcher's language, it's a $\Delta$-complex. One has a(n almost identical) form of simplicial homology for $\Delta$-complexes, though, so it doesn't really matter in practice.

Comment: are you sure that this is a triangulation for the Klein-bottle ?

Comment: =s so it isn't?

Comment: if I can calculate this via triangulation (not necessarily I'm saying I gotta use the triangulation from above) then you have helped me a lot by now, thank you all.

Comment: Certainly this is a CW-complex. In general, for finite CW complexes, the alternating sum of numbers of simplices equals the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Even without that line labelled $c$, you have one face, two edges, and one vertex, so you can get the Euler characteristic, etc.

Comment: This can be made into a triangulation however by barycentrically subdividing the complex twice. But calculating Euler characteristic out of it would be a bit tedious. Alternatively, you can see a simplicial homology of $\Delta$ complexes in Hatcher.